# Kitchen Counter top has small patch that is losing color

Tags: kitchen

My kitchen counter top has a small patch that is losing color. The patch is the main area of the countertop where my wife cuts veggies/processes food/other stuff.

I am looking for some fix to get it back in its original color since we live in a rented house, and this thing is not covered in the standard maintenance provided to us.

Comment: Is it possible to add a picture to help assess the type of damage? And if you know the type of material of which the counter is made, that will likely be relevant also.

Comment: In the meantime, get a cutting board large enough to absorb the wear and tear on a counter top. It might be a good habit to save your replacement.

Comment: If it is really a [Formica countertops](http://www.formica.com/en/ca/homeowner-knowledge/diy/diy-faqs), they have a page that gives tips and you can contact them for any problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a plastic laminate kitchen countertop, known better by the brand name Formica. You can try a permanent marker to try to give some color back, or I've also heard that using something like WD-40 or mineral oil can darken the light spot and make it less noticeable.

If that doesn't work, then painting the countertop with epoxy paint made for that purpose is really your only other option short of replacing the whole thing. If you decide to paint them, make sure to get approval from the owner.

Answer (score 1):

I had this at my last job  and the colour came back after a good rub with some Astonish cleaning paste [link to astonish at Amazon.co.uk](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Astonish-Multi-Use-Cleaning-Paste/dp/B0071QMHHK) - you don't state your locality but this must give some clues about a similar product. Astonish is quite thick and abrasive so be careful, and check it every few rubs to make sure you're not through the stain and working away on the actual surface.